# Android get application's internet usage

Tags: android, networking

There is an app (Es file explorer) which on startup connects to a certain site to check some parameters and then display an annoying message. I would like to block the access to this site, adding it to the /etc/hosts file: in this way the message won't be displayed. But i don't know this site. How can i get it? Is there a specific application to find it out?

Comment: What message does it displays?

Comment: Unlicensed version :|